# How to get two scalars on same chart with tensorboardX?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboardx

The docs seem to indicate that add_custom_scalars_multilinechart does it but it is not working.

Have something like this:

```
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter(comment='test')

writer.add_custom_scalars_multilinechart(['loss/train', 'loss/test'], title='losses')

for blahblah:
    ...
    writer.add_scalar('loss/train', loss.item(), epoch)
    writer.add_scalar('loss/test', loss_test.item(), epoch)
```

Comment: This now seems to be working. I'm not sure if tensorboard was in a bad state or had something cached. Clicking around appeared to trigger the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Plot two scalars on same chart with tensorboardX:

```
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
```

Create two summaryWriter for two scalars

```
writer_train = SummaryWriter('runs/train_0')
writer_test = SummaryWriter('runs/test_0')
```

Add scalars instances to the summaryWriter respective; they must have same tag, e.g.: "LOSS"

```
for data in loop:
    writer_train.add_scalar('LOSS', loss.data.item(), idx)
    writer_test.add_scalar('LOSS', loss_test.data.item(), idx)
```

For working code, please visit github: [Examples with tensorboardX](https://github.com/Public-course/TensorboardX)
(See more_plots_one_chat.py)

Tutorial: [TensorboardX](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)